# Format Numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a web page that allows a user to enter values into fields. When a user updates a field, I want to automatically update the total displayed to the user. Because the input fields are dynamically generated, I created a JavaScript function called "update". A sample of my code is shown here:

```
<input type="text" id="myField1" onchange="return update(this);" />
<input type="text" id="myField2" onchange="return update(this);" />
<span id="totalCount"></span>

var total = 0;
function update(e) {
  var v = $(e).val();
  if (parseInt(v) != NaN) {
    total = total + v;
    $("#totalCount").html(total);       
  }
  return false;
}
```

When a user enters "2" into "myField1", "02" is displayed in the "totalCount" element. In reality, I would like to just display "2". How do I do this in JavaScript while taking into a account odd entries?

Thanks!

Comment: When you input zero, does it display `00` or `0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `$(e).val()` is a string, `total + v` is a string too. Use `parseInt` not just for the test but also when using the value:

```
var v = parseInt($(e).val(), 10);
if (!isNaN(v)) {
    total = total + v;
    $("#totalCount").html(total);
}
```

Comment: Also `NaN != NaN` returns true use isNaN(v);

Comment: @Gumbo, what happens if he inputs a decimal, 2.15 for example?

Comment: @Marko: `parseInt` parses the input to integer. In case of `2.15` the output will be `2`.

Comment: Yeah I thought so too, was just thinking it might be something to consider if decimal input is allowed :) +1 either way

Comment: Regarding decimals, you can use Number($(e).val()) instead of parseInt($(e).val(), 10)

Comment: @Lars: I'd say `parseFloat`, but there's no difference, `Number` is correct, too. An even shorter way is to use `+$(e).val()` instead of `Number($(e).val())`.